# Microsoft Teams – Notification when someone becomes available

Tags: windows-10, notifications, microsoft-teams

In Microsoft Teams, is it possible to get a notification when another user change status from busy to available?

Let’s say I want to send a non-urgent message to my coworker Jane. I see that her status is set to busy and therefore I don’t want to disturb her right now.

It would be very convenient if I would be able to get a notification when she becomes green (i.e. available).

If I recall correctly this was possible in Office Communicator.

I could also send an e-mail, but I prefer to use Teams instead.

My client is the official Teams app for Windows 10.

Comment: Note that as of January 2024 this feature is not available in New Teams

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the Chat list, click the `...` to the right of a person/contact. From the context menu, select `Notify when available`.

[image]

You will receive a toast alert in Teams when the person's status changes to Available.

If you've not engaged in a chat with the person before, you'll need to search for them and click their name so they appear on your Chat list with a *draft* chat, and then follow the steps above.

Alternatively, navigate to `Settings` > `Notifications` > `People` and click `Edit`. From this page, you can search for people to add a status alert to.

[image]

Comment: You can also go to your settings, go to the "notification" category, and at the bottom, in the "status" category, press "manage status notifications." You can add people from here even if you have not chatted with them.

Comment: On that same note, does Teams notify the contact that their status is being monitored?

Comment: No, I don't believe so.

Comment: @4yl1n this has now been renamed to 'People' on the notifications page.

Comment: Be warned you will be notified for the rest of your life whenever that person is available, until you turn it off in the same place. Until Microsoft fixes that design.

Comment: @JamesR404 that's the whole point...